# Bash script that clone git repo

Tags: git-bash

```
remoteHost=git@github.com
remoteUser=Spiderworks007
remoteDir=~/repositories/exercism-haskell.git
remoteRepos=$(ssh -l $remoteUser $remoteHost "ls $remoteDir")
```

Here is the error I am getting. I am new to bash scripting and git repo's.

```
You appear to be using ssh to clone a git:// URL.
Make sure your core.gitProxy config option and the
GIT_PROXY_COMMAND environment variable are NOT set.
```

Comment: The error tells you exactly what to do: `Make sure your core.gitProxy config option and the GIT_PROXY_COMMAND environment variable are NOT set.`.

Comment: I am new to this and i dont know how to set that up can you give me some steps that would be really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not `ssh -l` (login) on github.com, meaning you cannot log in to github.com as you.

What you can do is use the SSH URL of the GitHub repo to clone it:

```
git clone git@github.com:Spiderworks007/exercism-haskell.git
```

You can adapt your script to execute that `git clone` command.